# Dynamically adding HTML form field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Since I cant use div inside forms, I wonder how can I add new field in the middle of the form (and I can't use `.append()` here) without reloading the page or rewriting the form? (using jQuery)

EDIT:
this is the HTML:

```
<form id="form-0" name="0">
<b>what is bla?</b><br>
<input type="radio" name="answerN" value="0"> aaa <br>
<input type="radio" name="answerN" value="1"> bbb <br>
<input type="radio" name="answerN" value="2"> ccc <br>
<input type="radio" name="answerN" value="3"> ddd <br>
//This is where I want to dynamically add the new radio or text line

<input type="submit" value="Submit your answer">
//but HERE is where .append() will put it!

</form>
```

Comment: You question doesn't make too much sense. What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried to slelect the one-before-last child of the form and use append to it but it didn't work

Comment: What makes you think you can't use `div` elements inside `form` elements?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

What seems to be confusing this thread is the difference between:

```
$('.selector').append("<input type='text'/>");
```

Which appends the target element as a child of the .selector.

And

```
$("<input type='text' />").appendTo('.selector');
```

Which appends the target element as a child of the .selector.

Note how the position of the target element & the .selector change when using the different methods.

What you want to do is this:

```
$(function() {

  // append input control at start of form
  $("<input type='text' value='' />")
     .attr("id", "myfieldid")
     .attr("name", "myfieldid")
     .prependTo("#form-0");

  // OR

  // append input control at end of form
  $("<input type='text' value='' />")
     .attr("id", "myfieldid")
     .attr("name", "myfieldid")
     .appendTo("#form-0");

  // OR

  // see .after() or .before() in the api.jquery.com library

});
```

Answer (score 14):

This will insert a new element after the input field with id "password".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var newInput = $("<input name='new_field' type='text'>");
  $('input#password').after(newInput);
});
```

Not sure if this answers your question.

Answer (score 12):

You can add any type of HTML with methods like `append` and `appendTo` (among others):

[jQuery manipulation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)

Example:

```
$('form#someform').append('<input type="text" name="something" id="something" />');
```

Answer (score 7):

something like so might work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $input = $("<input name='myField' type='text'>");
    $('#section2').append($input);
});
</script>

<form>
    <div id="section1"><!-- some controls--></div>
    <div id="section2"><!-- for dynamic controls--></div>
</form>
```

Comment: @Rob, @pixelbobby, tahnx but the thing is if have a full form, i cant use append because it will insert the line below the </from> tag so it wont be a part of the form, how can i insert the $input in the middle of the form?

Comment: @IlyaD - Append inserts the new element into the tag, in this case it will put the new input inside the form tags.

Comment: @llyaD, see my updated answer.  I've added code that would insert the control in a specific position inside the form.  Also, you can use `prepend()`, `insertAfter()`, and `insertBefore()` to place a control at a specific position within an element.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug with appendTo using a frameset ID appending to a FORM in Chrome.
Swapped out the attribute type directly with div and it works.