# Wordpress add new example?

Tags: wordpress

I'm a bit new to wordpress plugin coding.  I've been working on a plugin that will be very large, and contain many custom data structures.

I know this is a pretty general question, but I have a list of items (groups) on my options page.  I'd like the entire options page to just use the settings api, but this list needs to have items added/edited/deleted from it.  Does anyone have a good example of how to do this?

Comment: you mean you want other options to be added dynamically ? you just need to add them into the array of $options.. although if they do not exist, you will need to make a function that will assign a default value IF they exist ..

Comment: The idea was to have an array of values stored, but I'm not quiet sure how to build the UI in Wordpress to allow creation/editing/deletion of this list of items.

Comment: oh.. if the interface is your question, than you you would need javascript - in particular jQuery would be a good choice.

Comment: Is there no easy to use library (similar to the SettingsAPI) to help me? I feel this must be needed a lot.  As well, how would I handle multiple forms on the same page?  At this point, do I just need to get down and dirty with the POST variables, or are there any wrappers I should still be aware of?

Comment: Jquery qill be quite easy , you just need to append new elements of form . if they have the right structure , they will be included in the submit to the settings (as far as I know) .

Comment: I use jQuery quiet often, I'm seasoned at web development, my question was if there were any specifics I should know about when coding on top of Wordpress. And an example would be the best help of that, showing me how they structure their files, where they have their php processing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although I saw an exmple before - I can not remember where . But what I have tried to explain to you above is that first you need to add the elements using jQuery append like here : [Dynamically adding HTML form field using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099301/dynamically-adding-html-form-field-using-jquery) then, for the options, just create an array, like here described here : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/dynamic-options .