# How to add radio/checkbox data into form with other fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I am new in Jquery and I do not know how to add several radio/checkbox with other data types (text, number etc. in my case) into my function. I am using Java/Spring and there are several moments from they: .jsp files, spring:message etc. Help me please! Tanks.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editRow">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h2 class="modal-title"><spring:message code="company.add"/></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form:form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="detailsForm">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="control-label col-xs-3"><spring:message code="insurance.tableName"/></label>

                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="description" class="control-label col-xs-3"><spring:message code="insurance.tableDescription"/></label>

                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description"
                                   placeholder="Description">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="franchise" class="control-label col-xs-3"><spring:message code="insurance.tableFranchise"/></label>

                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="franchise" name="franchise"
                                   placeholder="1000">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="population" class="control-label col-sm-3"><spring:message code="insurance.tablePopulation"/></label>

                        <div class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="col-xs-2" id="population" name="population" value="Kiev"><spring:message code="insurance.kiev"/><br/>
                            <input type="radio" class="col-xs-2" id="population" name="population" value="Kiev district"><spring:message code="insurance.kievDistrict"/><br/>
                            <input type="radio" class="col-xs-2" id="population" name="population" value="more than 1 million"><spring:message code="insurance.moreOneMillion"/><br/>
                            <input type="radio" class="col-xs-2" id="population" name="population" value="to 1 million"><spring:message code="insurance.toOneMillion"/><br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="col-xs-2" id="population" name="population" value="to half of 1 million"><spring:message code="insurance.toHalfAMillion"/><br/>
                            <input type="radio" class="col-xs-2" id="population" name="population" value="more than 100 thousand"><spring:message code="insurance.moreOneHundred"/><br/>
                            <input type="radio" class="col-xs-2" id="population" name="population" value="to 100 thousand"><spring:message code="insurance.toOneHundred"/><br/>
                            <input type="radio" class="col-xs-2" id="population" name="population" value="other"><spring:message code="insurance.other"/><br/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="engine_power" class="control-label col-xs-3"><spring:message code="insurance.tableEngine_Power"/></label>

                        <div class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="col-xs-2" id="engine_power" name="engine_power" value="more than 3.0"><spring:message code="insurance.engineThree"/><br/>
                            <input type="radio" class="col-xs-2" id="engine_power" name="engine_power" value="more than 2.0"><spring:message code="insurance.engineTwo"/><br/>
                            <input type="radio" class="col-xs-2" id="engine_power" name="engine_power" value="more than 1.6"><spring:message code="insurance.engineOne"/><br/>
                            <input type="radio" class="col-xs-2" id="engine_power" name="engine_power" value="to 1.6"><spring:message code="insurance.engineToOne"/><br/>>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="amount" class="control-label col-xs-3"><spring:message code="insurance.tableAmount"/></label>

                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount"
                                   placeholder="1296">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><spring:message code="insurance.save"/></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My function:

```
var form;
function save() {
    form = $('#detailsForm')
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxUrl,
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $('#editRow').modal('hide');
            updateTable();
            successNoty('Saved');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically adding HTML form field using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099301/dynamically-adding-html-form-field-using-jquery)

Comment: Are you trying to use jQuery to get the values of radio and select elements?

Comment: or add custom form elements to other elements? Like Select boxes with multi-select check boxes or something?

Comment: No, I do not. I need to use these radio/checkboxes inside the one form with other fields like name, description etc. I do not know, how to get data from radio/checkbox and insert into my #detailsForm.Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I just replaced `radio` option to `select->option` with different values in my code and it works fine.