# Text spilling out of form group

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following input area added:

```
('#item').after('<div class="form-group" onsubmit="return false"></div><form action="javascript:void(-1)"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"> What?</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputSaleValue" placeholder="Enter value"><small id="emailHelp3" class="form-text text-muted">eg 10%</small><form onsubmit="return false"> </div>');
```

After pressing enter, I then have:

```
('#InputSaleValue').after('<div class="form-group" onsubmit="return false"></div><form action="javascript:void(-1)"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"> What?</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputCommission" placeholder="Enter value"><small id="emailHelp3" class="form-text text-muted">eg 10%</small><form onsubmit="return false"> </div>');
```

But what is happening is that the "eg 10%" is being added twice to the bottom of the second addition, and not to each addition separately.

Comment: Can you please provide a runnable example using the snippet function? (Ctrl+M)

Comment: Hi there, sorry, this is kind of what I mean:https://jsfiddle.net/n5f5m46m/

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because in your second code line, you're adding the template after `#InputSaleValue` which's just the input field & not the label, eg 10% included. So your content appearing just next to that field. You might wanna change the first line as :

```
$('#item').after('<div class="form-group" onsubmit="return false"></div><form action="javascript:void(-1)"><div id="saleField"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"> What?</label><input type="text" id="InputSaleValue" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter value"><small id="emailHelp3" class="form-text text-muted">eg 10%</small></div></form onsubmit="return false"> </div>');
```

And second line as

```
$('#saleField').after('<div class="form-group" onsubmit="return false"></div><form action="javascript:void(-1)"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"> What?</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputCommission" placeholder="Enter value"><small id="emailHelp3" class="form-text text-muted">eg 10%</small><form onsubmit="return false"> </div>');
```

In 1st line I've just enclosed that field including label, eg 10 inside `div` with id as `saleField`. And in second line I've made only change of selector. Here's link for working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/noxcWTmAaLwtYv8vx2CO?p=preview

Comment: 'onsubmit' is a FORM Attribute, so you can't  use it in DIV tag.

Comment: Agreed but I'm just recreating using given sample of code. And noting what he's missing. There're other wrong things also like having form inside form, instead having fields to be added inside single form, no form end tag, etc.. This must be only small part of complete code.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was it :) And helped me understand HTML a bit better, too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099301/dynamically-adding-html-form-field-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(function(){
$('#item').after('<form action="javascript:void(-1)" class="form-group" id="formArea" onsubmit="return false"><div class="form-group"><label for="inputSaleValue"> What?</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSaleValue" placeholder="Enter value"><small class="form-text text-muted">eg 10%</small></div></form>');

$('#inputSaleValue').on('keydown',function(e){
 if ((e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) && $(this).val() != '') {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#formArea').append('<div class="form-group"><label for="inputCommission"> What?</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputCommission" placeholder="Enter value"><small class="form-text text-muted">eg 10%</small></div>');
 }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="item"></div>
```