# How to add checkbox to form submission with jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I am developing a little website with webflow and must now write a tiny bit of custom code. To simplify and summ up, I have a checkbox that is outside fo the form tag. My goal is to write a little jquery of javascript code to "capture" the checkbox outside the form tag and add it to the form submission.

Here is what I came up with, but it's still not working. 
Would you have an idea ? I'm pretty new to code... thank you :)

**The script I would love to use: (if that makes sense?)**

```
<script>

// defines the variable for the form
var form = document.getElementById("reservation");

// add the checkbox with the id of "outsider" to the form submission
document.getElementById("outsider").addEventListener("click", function () {
  form.submit();
});

</script>
```

**EDIT:** I made some research before of course, but couldn't really understand the code snipet people were talking about and how to "link" the script to the actual submit button of my form.

**For modern browser:**

```
var checkedValue = document.querySelector('.outsider:checked').value;
```

**By using jQuery:**

```
var checkedValue = $('.outsider:checked').val();
```

**Pure javascript:**

```
var checkedValue = null; 
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('outsider');
    for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
          if(inputElements[i].checked){
               checkedValue = inputElements[i].value;
               break;
          }
    }
```

**Another javascript:**
*Again, not sure how to link the function to my submit button*

```
CheckboxHandler.isChecked = function (checkboxObj) {
  return(checkboxObj.checked == true);
};
```

Comment: so you want to add checkbox value to the form submission or submit the form when clicking on checkbox which one is your expected result ?

Comment: @VishalTajPM, thank you for your reply !

Exactely, I would like to add the checkbox value to the form submission. The expected result would be to get an email (after I clicked on "send") and having in written in my email the name of the checkbox and its value. 

Here are some screenshot for you :)
https://imgur.com/a/PwbTw

Answer (score 0):

For adding checkbox value you can add a `hidden` field to keep the value of `checkbox` so whenever we update the `checkbox` we update the `hidden` field also code will be as follows.

```js
var humanizeCheckbox = ['outsider', 'without outsider'];

$('input[name="outsider"]').val(humanizeCheckbox[1]);

$('#check').on('click', function(){
  $('input[name="outsider"]').val($(this).is(':checked') ? humanizeCheckbox[0] : humanizeCheckbox[1])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<form action='/' method="GET" >
  <input type="hidden" name="outsider" />
  <input type="text" name="email" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Interesting ! I see what you did there ! Love the logic behind it :) Thank you for having taken the time to do that. 

I tried to implement it into my webflow project, though the email I get now displays the "outsider" name but not it's checked value "true".
Am I missing something ?

Here some screenshots again :
https://imgur.com/a/6P7s0

Comment: is it after checking the checkbox or without checking? basically, the checkbox is boolean so if there is any humanized value we can update the `hidden` field using that and also if you want to set a default value to `hidden` also you can. i have updated the code please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a jQuery submit event to your `form`:

```
$("#reservation").submit(function(evt) {
    //handleChecbox
    $("#inside").val($('.outsider:checked').val());
});
```

This function will run before you actually submit the `form` but I recommend the addition of the item to the `form`.

Comment: Interesting ! Thank you Lajos !

I thought it'd be only one way to code things, seems to be many ways to get to what we want.

Unfortunately I still can't get the value (wether it's been checked or not) in my email confirmation. What am i missing ?

here some screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/lG986

Comment: @anthonysalamin can you show us your HTML and clarify what should be read and where should that value be put?

Comment: Of course @lajosarpad , here is the HTML for the outsider checkbox:

`<input type="checkbox" class="outsider" />`

And the HTML for the form containg the hidden checkbox:

`<script>
$("#reservation").submit(function(evt) {
    //handleCheckbox
    $("#inside").val($('.outsider:checked').val());
});
</script>

<!--begening of the form-->
<form action='/' method="get" id="reservation" >
  <input type="hidden" id="inside" />
  <input type="text" name="email" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>`

More screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/kE6DP

Comment: @anthonysalamin thanks. I have changed my code here to use your ids. If this does not solve your problem, then I kindly ask you to create a JSFiddle with a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example of your problem, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
so we will solve the problem at your experimental example which should help you integrate the solution into your project.

Comment: All right, thank you @lajosarpad !
here is the the link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anthonysalamin/nrx7vbst/9/#&togetherjs=hDhMlj7sxB

For example purpose, maybe I should generate an "alert pop up" to see if the script worked instead of willing to send an email. What do you think ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: could something like do the trick for me ? Is that an elegant way to aproach the problem ?

`var form = document.getElementById("reservation");
document.getElementById("outsider").addEventListener("click", function () {
  form.submit();
});`

Comment: @anthonysalamin sorry fot the late reply. Here is an update: https://jsfiddle.net/nrx7vbst/23/ Your version was almost correct, but jQuery as a library was not added to the Fiddle, also, to better testability I have made the inside visible, but you can use it as hidden at your real use-case. Finally, I have made sure that off will be the value if the checkbox is unchecked instead of empty value.

Comment: it's amazing !! It works and I could integrate the code within my webflow project !! Beautiful ! May I ask you another question ?

Comment: would it be possible to actually append checkboxes to the form element should I not have just one checkbox outside the form but several checkboxes with the same class and generated dynamicaly ?

I read something interesting here about apending element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099301/dynamically-adding-html-form-field-using-jquery

What are your thoughts on this, and how could I update your code to make it work for several checkboxes ? Hope you don't mind me asking :)

Comment: @anthonysalamin you can add elements to a form without a problem both before you initially send your HTML from server to browser or in the browser when your form is already rendered. These are surely possibilities you can rely on anytime. You can append anything to your form using $("#reservation").appent("your html to be appended") or, without jQuery: document.getElementById("reservation").innerHTML += "your html to be added"; This is how you can append an already rendered form. If this small comment is not informative enough, please, ask a separate question and share its link here.

Comment: Awesome ! Well I've tried a codpen with your idea but must be missing something. I created a new post, like you suggested. The question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538443/adding-multiple-checkboxes-to-a-form-element Thank you for your time as always !